# Structure and relevance of Sefer Yeshaya

Tags: gentiles, prophecies, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Was Yeshaya included in Tenach as all of it is relevant for all time?  If so, what is the relevance of chapter [13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1013.htm)-[22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1022.htm) for example. Is there any evidence that his prophecies to the other nations actually reached them?

Comment: Hi user2730 welcome to Mi Yodeya! These are some interesting questions, though perhaps it's best if you [edit] some out and [ask them again](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) in separate questions. I encourage you to register your account to gain access to many of Mi Yodeya's features and perhaps choose a more meaningful username (unless you have a special attachment to the number 2730). Hope to see you around!